# Linux Kernel Module debugging

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

Is there any method to debug Linux kernel module?

I am looking for a GUI based facility like the ones used for user processes?

Answer (score 2):

If you can run your kernel in a virtual machine, VMware Workstation lets [GDB attach to the VM](http://stackframe.blogspot.com/2007/04/debugging-linux-kernels-with.html) to debug the running kernel.  You can probably do the same with other VM platforms, though I'm not familiar with those.

There is also [KGDB](http://kgdb.linsyssoft.com/quickstart.htm) for debugging a kernel on bare hardware.  You connect to the target computer over its serial port.  I've used this a little, and it works, but VMware does it better.  Modern kernels have merged KGDB into mainline, so you won't need to patch.

That doesn't fully answer your question, because GDB isn't exactly a GUI-based tool on its own.  You'll have to find some GUI debugger that uses GDB's stub protocol for debugging or that wraps GDB with a usable interface.

Comment: Thank for your reply, but actually i have tested this remedy but newer version of kernel because of compiler optimization the generated vmlinux dos not have any debugging information! I could not find any way to disable it.

Comment: @amrzar: If your binary kernel/module has no debugging info, you won't find any common debugger that can help you.  Fortunately, the debugging info does exist.  If you're using your distribution's kernel, google to find the debug package.  If you're compiling your own, look in the "Kernel Hacking" menu for "Compile the kernel with debug info".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if u want GUI, then virtualization and kgdb is needed.  Eg, VirtualBox running linux with kernel module to be debugged, and host is another linux.

http://allmybrain.com/2010/04/29/debugging-linux-kernel-modules-with-virtualbox-and-kgdb/

I have done it for Linux and OpenSolaris, and I must say VirtualBox is really superb for understanding things happening in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of any GUI based debug utility but so far what I've used from my SOC kernel perspective:

#### **ftrace** - Function tracer

Many docs and tutorials over internet. Some [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/trace/ftrace.html) and [here official](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt). Also videos on youtube from Steven Rostedt main author, developer, and maintainer of the tool.
You can also use `ftrace_printk` messages instead of `dev_dbg`, `dev_err` and `dev_*` familly (also better than default `printk`).

Must enable those bellow when building the kernel

```
CONFIG_FUNCTION_TRACER
CONFIG_FUNCTION_GRAPH_TRACER
CONFIG_STACK_TRACER
CONFIG_DYNAMIC_FTRACE
```

Other option included is the [KernelShark](https://www.kernelshark.org/Documentation.html) front-end for ftrace.

#### IPC Logging (Qualcomm Linux kernel)

Some modules are build using the ipc logging system. Enabled with `CONFIG_IPC_LOGGING=y` on kernel build. And read from `/sys/kernel/debug/ipc_logging/[module_name]`

#### DMESG

Reading messages from buffer of the kernel logging (`dmesg`) for the standard `printk` family functions. Good also to enable `CONFIG_MESSAGE_LOGLEVEL_DEFAULT=7` on kernel build.